How to make Doxygen ignore function-like macro?
I have multiple classes defined as follows:
class MyClass : public virtual Parent
{
    MY_INTERFACE(MyClass, Parent)

    void someFunction();
}

Doxygen does not see the contents of such classes (someFunction, and further) because of MY_INTERFACE macro (which is defined in a different file which I do not proccess with Doxygen). Interestingly, this happens randomly (as it seems). I have two different classes with definition layout as above (even spaces and newlines are typed identically) and the first class is processed correctly with all its contents, while the other seems to be empty.
I have tried enabling SKIP_FUNCTION_MACRO, adding MY_INTERFACE(*) into EXCLUDE_SYMBOLS - it is all the same. Preprocessing is enabled.
The same thing happens in similar cases with different macros.

your classes are missing a ;

Does the Doxygen mechanism for How can I make Doxygen ignore some code fragment? not work?

Which version of doxygen are you using? did you have a look at the configuration setting SKIP_FUNCTION_MACROS

@albert Yes, that's been stated in the question, if I understand your suggestion correctly.

@Eljay I don't want to litter the code. I have this macros thousand times in the code, I can't place DOXYGEN_SHOULD_SKIP_THIS everywhere.

@463035818_is_not_an_ai what do you mean?

the code does not compile, because it misses ; (and I would expect doxygen to either get confused or produce an error, but I suppose its just a typo while typing the code here)

@463035818_is_not_an_ai as there is no info about the macro we don't know whether or not the code will compile, maybe the macro contains the ;.

@albert OP says someFunction is inside the class. OP also says that what they show is a class definition

@SigmaKlim oops missed the remark in the question about SKIP_FUNCTION_MACROS, looks like there is also some interaction with the MACRO_EXPANSION setting. Maybe best to open a discussion at https://github.com/doxygen/doxygen/discussions as you say "Interestingly, this happens randomly (as it seems)" when having multiple files, and at GitHub you can easily add a small complete example.

@SigmaKlim maybe anonther idea the setting PREDEFINED = MY_INTERFACE(x,y)=
